# view admin_menu not found in laravel voyager

Tags: laravel, voyager

My question is exactly like this [question](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/4074) but the difference is, everything works in `local` and this error comes in `server`

below are the errors from laravel-logs

[image: voyager_error_server]

I already try:

`php artisan view:clear`

`php artisan config:clear`

`php artisan route:clear`

`php artisan cache:clear`

my voyager version is `"^1.1"` in composer.json

Comment: Have you verified that the file is actually there? Because if it's not, Laravel is right about complaining. If it is there, check the file permissions

Comment: yes the file is there, and file permission is set to 644

Comment: Are you using php-fpm? If so, maybe try restarting the process

Comment: also check following things:
1) php version (local and server)
2) laravel required module of php (as per php version) (local and server)

Comment: the php version of local is same, the website is working (home page) but this errors come only in `/admin` where the voyager is used